# how create qtCreator project from a git repository?

Tags: qt, ide, project, cmake, qt-creator

I had created project. New File or Project=>git Repository Clone=> clone url git://github.com/negativ/eiskaltdcpp.git=>The process terminated with exit code 0.=> finish => cmake wizard =>next

=> what arguments writes here?

=> Simple, run cmake!

> Blockquote 
>   CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:70 (MESSAGE):
>     Could NOT find BZip2 (missing: BZIP2_LIBRARIES BZIP2_INCLUDE_DIR)
>   Call Stack (most recent call first):
>     /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBZip2.cmake:30 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
>     CMakeLists.txt:69 (find_package)
>   -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

=>Unable to open the project '/home/knowill/IT/dcproject/repository/negativ-eiskaltdcpp/CMakeLists.txt'.

help me, please. I'm sorry, if makes errors in question.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install bzip2` or `sudo yum install bzip2`

Comment: solutions,apt-get install openssl-dev boost-devel zlib-dev libz-dev libbz2-dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your version of cmake doesn't have BZip2 support. Confirm the required cmake and update if necessary and you should be in good shape.